# How to use switch statement to assign a string value to a variable

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, pointers, switch-statement

The purpose of my program is to calculate the expenses for a trip between various cities. The program will give a list of source cities, followed by a list of destination cities. The user will be allowed to choose their cities by inputting the first letter of each city.

I want the program to be able to take the input from the user and assign it to one of the given cities.

```
//Declarations
    char src_city[15];
    char dest_city[15];
```

```
system("cls");
    puts("\n");
    printf("ENTER THE SOURCE CITY: \n\n");
    printf("B for Baltimore\n\n");
    printf("C for Chattanooga\n\n");
    printf("N for Nashville\n\n");
    printf("P for Pasadena\n\n");
    puts("");
    scanf("%c", &src_city);
    switch(src_city)
    {
    case 'B': case 'b': ("Baltimore");
    break;
    case 'C': case 'c': ("Chattanooga");
    break;
    case 'N': case 'n': ("Nashville");
    break;
    case 'P': case 'p': ("Pasadena");
    break;
    }
    getchar();
```

The 'B', 'C', 'N', and 'P' are the letters I want the user to input, and when they do to assign it to the corresponding city.

However, when I use this method I get the error:

> "assignment to expression with array type".

I looked up this error and I was then told to use if/else if statements which in turn failed similarly. The switch statement method makes the most sense to me.

I need to assign the string value to the corresponding variable (`src_city`/`dest_city`) because I will need to call those variables later in a `printf()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show the actual code which has problem, but guessing from the problem description (*"assignment to expression with array type"*), you are trying something like

```
  src_city = "Baltimore";
```

which is invalid, as a variable of type array is not a modifiable lvalue and hence cannot be assigned to. You need to use [`strcpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy), like

```
 strcpy(src_city , "Baltimore");
```